# Where can I find proofs related to discrete or continuous random variables?

Tags: probability-theory

I which books can I find probability proofs like that of the linearity of the expectation, i.e., a proof for $\mathrm{E}(X+Y) = \mathrm{E}(X) + \mathrm{E}(Y)$, even when $X$ and $Y$ might NOT be independent?

Please note that the random variables $X$ and $Y$ can be discrete or continuous.

Comment: What definition(s) of expectation are you using? $\:$ The measure theory definition or one for discrete random variables and one for continuous random variables? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: One for discrete/continuous rv

Answer (score 0):

I read Introduction to Probability Theory by Blitzstein and Hwang and thought it was good.

Expectation is discusses in chapter 4, including a proof for linearity of expectation for the discrete case.
In chapter 5 they discuss continuous random variables and in chapter 7 give a proof of linearity of expectation for two continuous random variables (they use "LOTUS" for that, namely that: $
E\left(g\left(X,Y\right)\right)=\int_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\int_{y\in\mathbb{R}}g\left(x,y\right)f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)dydx $ for continuous random variables $X,Y$, where $f_{X,Y}\left(x,y\right)$ is their joint probability density function). I do not think that they prove "LOTUS" however so you do not really get it from first principles.